# How to build a empty android git server?

Tags: android, git, transfer, repository

I have a whole android project code,it is very different from google's,because a team have developed on it for one year.Now I decide to use git instead of svn.And **I want to use repo script** to maintain the project.How to transfer?I've try to mirror a git server from Google via

`repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/mirror/manifest --mirror`

then build my branch,but when I merge my project code to it,it is too difficult.
  Is there a easy way?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am working on this same issue, the most progress I have made is due to [this google group discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/repo-discuss/browse_thread/thread/a970482df8d5574e/17437b2098ab0e60).

From what I can tell you are going to have to maintain projects individually using git (I think you can do a `repo start` instead of `git branch` to setup your branches, then when you are ready to push changes you can use `git push` to the mirror. The thing you can gain from the repo script is the ability to use `repo sync` to sync all of the projects, and `repo start` to make new branches.

Could you be more specific about the problem you ran into with the merge? I may be able to help more on that front.